# How to change xml value in local project file with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, xml

I have a web project that I made with HTML-Javascript. I want to use the XML file (in local project folders) in this web project in javascript. Then I want to make a few changes in this XML file and overwrite the same xml file again. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript runs in the browser and is isolated from the local system. So the usual way is to upload/download the file. However here are several possibilities.

#### A small server application

Develop and start a small server application for example with node.js. The server part will provide the file system access.

#### Use a wrapper

A more advanced version of the previous solution, you encapsulate the web application using a wrapper like [Electron](https://www.electronjs.org/).

#### File System Access API

Use the [File System Access API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File_System_Access_API) available in some of the new Chromium based browsers.